# Amplify AppSync IAM not working in AppSync console

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Here's the problem:

I have a Vue app using Amplify DataStore and Auth. I migrated to the new Transformer v2 and am having problems with authorization.

I have selected AWS_IAM as the default authentication method and Amazon Cognito User Pool  as the additional authorization provider (I have also tried the user pool as the default and IAM as the additional authorizer).

Everything worked as expected prior to the migration. After the migration It seems to work in the browser (i.e. unauthorised users can sync the data from the DataStore and do queries and signed in users (via cognito) can also sync data and do queries). BUT not in the appSync console!

I am only able to access the data after logging in via cognito but not with IAM. Using IAM I get an unauthorized errorType with the message "Not Authorized to access listMerchants on type ModelMerchantConnection" – this happens no matter the query. This makes me believe that the policy attached to the unauthorised role does not contain the allow permission for the console to access the data.

Looking at the  role, I see two (what seems to be auto-generated policies) that refer to an appSync api – they have an ARN but I don't know where to find my API's ARN! - I thought I could create a test policy to see if the policy is the problem.

I also need some advice on the following, in the DataStore docs I don't see andy reference to configure the DataStore to use AuthModeStrategyType.MULTI_AUTH. I did however see an article somewhere where I mentioned that it should be configured, using:

```
DataStore: {
        authModeStrategyType: AuthModeStrategyType.MULTI_AUTH
      }
```

I'll gladly supply more details if needed. Hopefully the above is sufficient to point me in the right direction.

Appreciate any help

Comment: I have same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @ManuelGnerlich sorry, no i have not managed to solve the problem